# How do I size a background image to fit the web page?

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS but I wanted to try creating a login page to familiarize myself with the code. Below I have tried to create a hero image that is responsive and allows me to see the content on top of it. My end goal being a box in the center asking for an email and password.

How do I get the background image to size correctly and not cause the site to be scrollable?
Also not quite sure on the gridding or if it is the causing issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="hero-image">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div id="top">1</div>
        <div id="lefts">2</div>
        <div id="insert">
            <form>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="rights">4</div>
        <div id="bottom">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}


.hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),url("Background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 50%;
}

.grid-container:nth-child(odd){

}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(150px, auto);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(300px, auto);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-row: auto;
    grid-column: auto;
}

#top {
    grid-column: span 3;
    grid-row: span .75;
    color: green;
}

#lefts {
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;
}
#insert {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;
}

#rights {
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;

}

#bottom {
    grid-column: span 3;
    grid-row: span 2;
}

#password {
    text-align: left
}
```

Again very sorry as this was more or less last resort I've tried checking tutorials and documentation for the past 5 hours being still confused.

Comment: please merge CSS and HTML together so it can be parsed. Also your CSS is cut off. You start with CSS elements without a belonging class or ID.

Comment: @tacoshy By parsed do you want me to put ```<style>``` tags in the HTML? I already have it linked just didn't put in the code.

Comment: no. You currently use a snippet for HTML code and additionally a snipped for the CSS code. You can put both in the same snippet. There are 3 fields (HTML, CSS and JS). If you put CSS into the CSS field and HTML into the HTML field, you can press a "run button" which parses the code and displays like it would on a real website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inline style on the .hero-image class. You should avoid adding images in css as much as possible. For gradients/overlays, its best to use pseudo elements. You will have to add position: relative & a z-index to form so the overlay wont appear over the top of the div

```
<div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('Background.jpg);">
</div>

.hero-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 50%; 
  position: relative;
}
.hero-image::after{
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
     rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,0.8));
}
```

Comment: The last line in the css code is giving me an error of mismatched parameters. More specifically an error with: [, <color-stop>]+

Comment: bracket was missing from the linear gradient property. Try to troubleshoot this kind of stuff

Comment: That's what I originally thought was the issue but it still is showing as an error after I fixed it. Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/b37a5ee5a291f9839d49affd43c99ef1

Comment: checkout your markup & css. ive added another example of a linear gradient.

Comment: It is now accepting that code, but the site still scrolls I've tried changes in background-size but nothing is successful.

Comment: check your image url links to the correct directory in your project folder. this method of using background image wont effect scroll. there must be another issue somewhere. you probably wont need height: 100% on your body. for more info, we ideally need a codepen or example to troubleshoot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220244/discussion-between-protical-and-beatnik).

Comment: remove body 100%. add height 100vh to .hero-image. you dont really need to use grid for this kind of layout. use your browser dev tools more to troubleshoot. we need a link or codepen to troubleshoot more.

Comment: That cuts off the bottom half of the image but still causes the site to allow scroll. I believe the issue is with my gridding I will need to look back at it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is achieve full page background image, or just a background image for some element (like header). If it's a full page, then you will want to use `background-size: cover`, together with url of course, on html or body element:

```
html { 
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300') no-repeat center center scroll; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

On an element you will also want to use `background-size: cover`, but with several additions to control the size:

```
section {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can manipulate the height value to adjust its size for your purposes.